# Why must $\cos^{2}x = |\cos^{n}x|$ and not $\cos^{2}x = |\sin^{n}x|$?

Tags: trigonometry, contest-math

I was trying to solve the problem of finding the set of solutions of $x$ where $\cos^{n}x - \sin^{n}(x) = 1$, and the solution rested on equating $|\cos^{n}x| + |\sin^{n}x| = \sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1$, so then $|\cos^{n}x| = \cos^2x$(and similarly with $\sin$), but I don't see where that jump came from. Why do the $\cos$ terms have to match?

I understand the rest of the solution, but I feel like I may be missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that $\cos^n x \leq \cos^2 x$ for all $n \geq 2$. Likewise $\sin^n x \leq \sin^2 x$ for all $n \geq 2$. Now consider
\begin{align*}
\cos^n x - \sin^n x & =1\\
\cos^n x - \sin^n x & =\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x\\
\underbrace{(\cos^2 x -\cos^n x)}_{\geq 0} + \underbrace{(\sin^2 x+\sin^n x)}_{\geq 0} & =0.
\end{align*}
Thus both terms have to be zero for this to hold.

Answer (score 0):

I think the point is that if $n > 2$ and $x$ is real, 
$|\cos(x)|^n \le \cos(x)^2$ and $|\sin(x)|^n \le \sin(x)^2$,  so
$|\cos(x)|^n + |\sin(x)|^n \le \cos(x)^2 +  \sin(x)^2 = 1$, with equality only when $|\cos(x)|^n = \cos(x)^2$ and $|\sin(x)|^n = \sin(x)^2$.